# Error while trying to generate meanjs with yo

Tags: javascript, npm, yeoman, mean

I have installed yeoman globally and when I'm trying to generate meanjs with yo, there is an error and couldn't figure it out what is the main problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hEyh.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

I have also tried with sudo but it also didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your npm directory has the wrong permissions. Try:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

As a side note try [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), I found it leads to less permissions problems and you can install multiple versions along side each other.

Comment: It's very clearly not a yeoman problem, it's an NPM problem. NPM doesn't have the permissions to create a directory under `/Users/Kiknag/.npm/readable-stream/1.0.12-1`, this usually occurs if a user with elevated permissions modifies the directory or if you have accidentally changed the permissions on that directory. Could you add the output of `cd /Users/Kiknag && ls -la | grep .npm` to your original post?

Comment: Like I said, using nvm and never using `sudo` will prevent this problem in future. I've seen it happen lots of times before which is why I'm so confident.